MySQL Query of Adding or Editing a Woocommerce Product
I wanted to link a product inventory database to a Woocommerce Database but I need to be working on a different app, that links these 2 databases.
I tried to be building a CSV file each day and importing it to Woocommerce but its less efficient, I want to make a conection between this 2 databases, but I know very little about how Woocommerce works in the inside.
What i'm asking is, what's the Query that Woocommerce does to its database each time it creates, edits or deletes a product.
I would appreciate any help.

Turn on mysql query log, then create, update, delete a product, then check out the query log. After that do not forget to turn query log off.
